# Removing elements from an array whose value matches a specified string

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Vice President [1] =>   [2] => other [3] => Treasurer )
```

and I want delete the value with `other` in the value.

I try to use `array_filter` to filter this word, but `array_filter` will delete all the empty values, too.

I want the result to be like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Vice President [1] =>   [2] => Treasurer )
```

This is my PHP filter code:

```
function filter($element) {
  $bad_words = array('other');  

  list($name, $extension) = explode(".", $element);
  if(in_array($name, $bad_words))
    return;

  return $element;
}

$sport_level_new_arr = array_filter($sport_level_name_arr, "filter");

$sport_level_new_arr = array_values($sport_level_new_arr);

$sport_level_name = serialize($sport_level_new_arr);
```

Can I use another method to filter this word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach($sport_level_name_arr as $key => $value) {

  if(in_array($value, $bad_words)) {  
    unset($sport_level_name_arr[$key])
  }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't renumber the array like the OP wanted.

Comment: Hey EdoDodo
Just need use php function "array_values",

Comment: This code is missing the `;` at the end of the `unset` line 4.

Answer (score 7):

[`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) is the right function. Ensure your callback function has the correct logic.

Try the following:

```
function other_test($var) {
    // returns whether the value is 'other'
    return ($var != 'other');
}

$new_arr = array_filter($arr, 'other_test');
```

**Note:** if you want to reindex the array, then you could call `$new_arr = array_values($new_arr);` after the above.

Answer (score 2):

This will create two arrays and will find the difference.  In the second array we will put the elements to exclude:

```
array_values(array_diff($arr,array("other")));
```

Comment: it will create two array and will find the diffrence, in the second array the we will put the elements to exclude

Answer (score 0):

> If the callback function returns true, the current value from input is returned into the result array. [PHP Manual](http://php.net/function.array-filter)

So you need to do `return true;` in your `filter();` function instead of `return $element;` to make sure that no empty values are removed.